# Solr : Ignore rows not having required field while indexing using CSV

Tags: csv, solr, lucene, solrj

I want to perform indexing in Solr using CSV file. Solr throws an error if there is even a single row having empty required field, it stops whole indexing, as result I get no row indexed. I want to know how do I ignore such rows without required fields and perform indexing on only rows having required fields. Following is the entry for column in schema.xml :

```
<field name="XXXX" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

1. You can provide default value for the field in [the schema definition](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Defining+Fields)
2. You can provide default value for the field in the custom update request processor chain ([DefaultValueUpdateProcessorFactory](http://www.solr-start.com/info/update-request-processors/#DefaultValueUpdateProcessorFactory))
3. With Solr 6.1, you can ignore the record that's causing an error, also in the custom URP chain ([TolerantUpdateProcessorFactory](http://www.solr-start.com/info/update-request-processors/#TolerantUpdateProcessorFactory))

Comment: Interesting... I didn't known the existence of a default value field parameter in schema definition. I'll remove my answer :)